# Running FaceNet in real time for face recognition using openCV and mtcnn

Tags: artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, facenet

I have generated a .npz file which Have the face embeddings and I can recognise faces from images but I can't implement in real time.

Here is the code that I'm trying :

`import cv2
import numpy as np
from mtcnn import MTCNN
import tensorflow as tf

detector = MTCNN()`

## Load the FaceNet model

`model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')`

## Load the .npz file containing the embeddings

`npzfile = np.load('test-embeddings.npz') embeddings = npzfile['embeddings']`

## Create a video capture object

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

`while True:
# Get the next frame from the video
ret, frame = cap.read()

```
# Detect faces in the frame
faces = detector.detect_faces(frame)

# Loop over the detected faces
for face in faces:
    x,y,w,h = face['box']
    # Extract the face region from the frame
    face = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # Preprocess the face image
    face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
    face = face.astype('float32') / 255.0
    face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

    # Extract the embedding of the face
    embedding = model.predict(face)

    # Find the closest match to the embedding in the .npz file
    best_match = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(embeddings-embedding, axis=1))

    # Display the name of the person corresponding to the closest match on the screen
    cv2.putText(frame, npzfile['names'][best_match], (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the frame on the screen
cv2.imshow('Face Recognition', frame)

# If the user presses the `q` key, stop the loop
if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break`
```

## Release the video capture object

`cap.release()`

## Close all open windows

`cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

but ist's showing errors like:

`File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\MTCNN_Face_Detection-in-real_time-and-images-with-fecial-land-marks--main\real-time-facenet.py", line 13, in <module> embeddings = npzfile['embeddings'] ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 260, in __getitem__ raise KeyError("%s is not a file in the archive" % key) KeyError: 'embeddings is not a file in the archive'`